# Segmentation Fault on Simple Function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation fault 11 when I call this function

```
    void flexibleArray(int *array, int *length) {
    int cnt = 0, number = 0;
    while (number!=-1) {
        printf("\nInsert the variable :"); scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number!=-1){
            cnt++;
            array = realloc(array, cnt * sizeof(int));
            array[cnt-1] = number;
        }
    }
    *length = cnt;
}
```

as

```
int *array = NULL, arrayLength;
flexibleArray(array, &arrayLength);
```

It's a really simple function that I've always used and I don't get why is it giving me this error right now. I've been playing with it around to try to nail down the line that's giving me the problem, and I found out that taking off the `*length = cnt;` line apparently doesn't give me the problem. Can I avoid the error keeping that line?
Thanks

CORRECT CODE:

```
   int* flexibleArray(int *length) {
    int *flexArray = NULL;
    int cnt = 0, number = 0;
    while (number!=-1) {
        printf("\nInsert the variable :"); scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number!=-1){
            cnt++;
            flexArray = realloc(flexArray, cnt * sizeof(int));
            flexArray[cnt-1] = number;
        }
    }
    *length = cnt;
    return flexArray;
}
```

and in main()

```
int *array = NULL, arrayLength;
array = flexibleArray(&arrayLength);
```

Comment: When you call the function, what is `array` and how is it defined?

Comment: You do the `realloc`, possibly writing a new pointer to `array` , then you write to it... and then what? You don't `return` or otherwise save `array` anywhere. The old `array` that was passed to the function is now possibly invalid, and the memory that might have been allocated by `realloc` is leaked.

Comment: as a pointer initialised to null, while arrayLength is just defined as int and not initialised

Comment: You should [edit] the question and show at least the declaration and if applicable the allocation of `array` and `arrayLength` in the calling function. Passing an `int *` is wrong since you want to reallocate the memory. The calling function will not get the modified pointer because `flexibleArray` will modify its local copy only. You would have to pass the address of the pointer, i.e. a `int **`

Comment: ...or, return the new pointer and do: `int *array = flexibleArray(&arrayLength);`

Comment: @Bodo thanks, then I should study better the pointers. I didn't think that it used only a local variable of the pointer

Comment: @L_Cleo Returning the modified pointer would also be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> as a pointer initialised to null, while arrayLength is just defined as
>   int and not initialised

In that case you need to pass its reference to function.

```
flexibleArray(&array, &arrayLength);
```

And function will become

```
void flexibleArray(int **array, int *length) {
    int cnt = 0, number = 0;
    while (number!=-1) {
        printf("\nInsert the variable :"); scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number!=-1){
            cnt++;
            *array = realloc(*array, cnt * sizeof(int));
            (*array)[cnt-1] = number;
        }
    }
    *length = cnt;
}
```

Or

return new pointer from the function.

```
int *flexibleArray(int *array, int *length)
{
  ....
  return array;
}
```

from `main`

```
array = flexibleArray(array, &arrayLength);
```

Comment: I went for the second option, although the first one seems more clean. It's also a little bit confusing though. Thank you anyways